# Using Input radio inside Blazor and allowing nullable Enum

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

I work on a Blazor WebAssembly project and I need to display input radio buttons based on Enum.

[image]

Below is my 'InputRadio.razor'

```
    @using System.Globalization
    @typeparam TValue
    @inherits InputBase<TValue>

    <input @attributes="AdditionalAttributes" type="radio" value="@SelectedValue" checked="@(SelectedValue.Equals(Value))" @onchange="OnChange" />

    @code {
        [Parameter]
        public TValue SelectedValue { get; set; }
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback<ChangeEventArgs> SelectedValueChanged { get; set; }

        private void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Value is "on") {            // <------- only way to test if value is null. Why "on" ??? 
                CurrentValueAsString = null;
            } else {
                CurrentValueAsString = args.Value.ToString();
            }
            SelectedValueChanged.InvokeAsync(args);
        }

        protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result, out string errorMessage)
        {
            var success = BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var parsedValue);
            if (success)
            {
                result = parsedValue;
                errorMessage = null;

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = default;
                errorMessage = $"{FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field isn't valid.";

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is my 'Test.razor'

```
<EditForm Model="CurrentFilterModel">
<InputRadio name="difficulty" SelectedValue="null"                        SelectedValueChanged="FilterCourses" @bind-Value="@CurrentFilterModel.DifficultyFilter" /> All
<InputRadio name="difficulty" SelectedValue="EnumDifficulty.Beginner"     SelectedValueChanged="FilterCourses" @bind-Value="@CurrentFilterModel.DifficultyFilter" /> Beginner
<InputRadio name="difficulty" SelectedValue="EnumDifficulty.Intermediate" SelectedValueChanged="FilterCourses" @bind-Value="@CurrentFilterModel.DifficultyFilter" /> Intermediate
<InputRadio name="difficulty" SelectedValue="EnumDifficulty.Advanced"     SelectedValueChanged="FilterCourses" @bind-Value="@CurrentFilterModel.DifficultyFilter" /> Advanced
</EditForm>
```

Below the 'Test.cs'

```
public enum EnumDifficulty
{
    Beginner,
    Intermediate,
    Advanced
}

public FilterModel CurrentFilterModel = new FilterModel();

public class FilterModel
{
   public EnumDifficulty? DifficultyFilter { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

As you can see, the `DifficultyFilter` filter used is nullable. When null I know this filter is not set.

This implementation works. Each time a radio button is selected the `onchange` event is triggered. I had hard time handling the `null` value. After searching and trying things, I discovered that the test `if (args.Value is "on") ...` allowed me to manage `null` values. But why **"on"** ? I have no clue. Please take a look at my code above.

Some of you may suggest me to adjust my `Enum` like that:

```
public enum EnumDifficulty
{
    Any,     // <--- added 
    Beginner,
    Intermediate,
    Advanced
}
```

But I don't want that because this Enum is also used on my Entity Framework model and this is not a valid choice.

** UPDATE **

Below is the full code for TryParseValueFromString

```
protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, out TValue result, out string errorMessage)
{
    if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(string))
    {
        result = (TValue)(object)value;
        errorMessage = null;
        return true;
    }
    else if (typeof(TValue).IsNullableEnum()) // (typeof(TValue).IsEnum) 
    {
        var success = BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var parsedValue);
        if (success)
        {
            result = parsedValue;
            errorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = default;
            errorMessage = $"The {FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is not valid.";
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(int))
    {
        if (int.TryParse(value, out var resultInt))
        {
            result = (TValue)(object)resultInt;
            errorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = default;
            errorMessage = "The chosen value is not a valid number.";
            return false;
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException($"{GetType()} does not support the type '{typeof(TValue)}'.");
}

public static class CustomStaticFunctions
{
    public static bool IsNullableEnum(this Type t)
    {
        Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
        return (u != null) && u.IsEnum;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is your question !? What do you want to know ? What is "on?"

"on" is the value assigned to a radio group when the value attribute of a selected
radio button is missing. This is from my previous knowledge. My new knowledge (hope I'm right) comes from you, meaning that the value attribute should not necessarily be missing to result in the value "on"...it's enough that the value attribute is empty (perhaps null or empty string) to give us the value "on".

Are you sure your component is working ? Your code is missing this part to check enum values:

```
   else if (typeof(TValue).IsEnum) 
    {
        var success = BindConverter.TryConvertTo<TValue>(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out var parsedValue);
        if (success)
        {
            result = parsedValue;
            validationErrorMessage = null;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = default;
            validationErrorMessage = $"The {FieldIdentifier.FieldName} field is not valid.";
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @enet. You responded to my question that was to know about this "on" value. Any documentation on that behaviour somewhere ? Do you think this is sufficient to check this 'on' value whether this is null value selected ? And you are right my code is missing some part but that was removed for clarity. In my case I was only working on Enum values in my radio button. Now I added all missing parts (see my update above).

Comment: @Bronzato, what you did works perfectly well. You can read about the "on" value here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio, under the sub title: Data representation of a radio group